# Extend vector fields from several $S^1$ to $D^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let's take a disk $D^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $n$ holes ($n = 0, 1, ...$).

In case $n = 0, 1$ it's clear how to extend any non-zero (i.e. with no singular points) vector field from $S^1$ to disk in first case and a ring in the second.

I expect that in case $n > 1$ it's also possible to extend vector field initially set on each of $S^1$ of inner holes to the whole $D^2$.

More formally, let $\{S^1\}_{i=1..n}$ - borders of holes in $D^2$ and $v|_{S^1 _{i}}$ are provided. How to extend $v$ to the whole $D^2$?

Comment: Probably it's not clear what I am asking. For a ring $R$ (a disk with a single hole) you can extend any nonvanishing vector field from inner $S^1$ (by constant vector on each radius for example). I am interested in case where we have two holes and field being specified on each of them (with different winding number in general case). In fact this is all about homotopic classification of vector fields on $U$.

Comment: Suppose you have a vector field specified on $\partial U$, where $U$ is $D^2$ minus some open discs. Now extend this to $\partial U \times [0,\varepsilon]$ - a neighborhood of the boundary. Once you've done this, extend along 'strips' between the discs so that the boundary of your thickened neighborhood and the strips is a circle, and its complement is an open disc. Now you're reduced to extending a vector field on $S^1$ to a disc. This is the same thing as asking that the vector field, as a map $S^1 \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$, is null-homotopic.

Comment: And to check this you tally up the contributions of all the indices of the individual circles. Some examples might help, but I'm not up to the task of drawing and uploading pictures right now. ($D^2$ with two discs remvoed from the interior is a good example to work with.)

Comment: Can't grasp the picture at the moment. Will try to think tomorrow too. 'Strips' are the wide lines connecting holes? So holes with these 'strips' connecting them together make a one big hole? If we apply this construction to thickened Nh  we will get a thickened ring, right? So, looks like you are talking about some other construction.